# Not able to access the pageY, pageX fields of event

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

**UPDATE: Since the click event was wired up with an element in the kendo UI Grid control, the event was undefined. My colleague suggested to use window.event.clientX and it worked. Thanks.**

I am trying to access the pageX, pageY fields inside a javascript function but it does throws up an exception as pageX being not a property of event. I am also new to client side coding. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code.

```
function showDetails(e) {
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: '/List/Reader',
                        type: 'json'
                    }).success(function (data, status, xhr) 
                    {
                        readers = data;
                        $("#cardholderdetails").html("");
                        var length = data.length;
                        for( var i = length-1;i>length-3; i--)
                            $("#cardholderdetails").append("<img src = " + readers[i].FileName + " width='60' height='60' id='cardholderpic'/><span>" + readers[i].Name1 + "</span><br/>");
                        $("#cardholderdetails").css('top', e.pageY+20).css('left', e.pageX+10);
                        $("#hider").append("<a id='buttonClose' href=javascript:close()>Close</a>");
                        $("#hider").fadeIn("slow");
                        $('#cardholderdetails').fadeIn("slow");
                    }).error(function (status, error) {
                        alert("Failed to retrieve alarms");
                    });

            }
```

What am i missing.

Comment: Since when the intellisense is the thing that count?

Comment: Since you mention Intellisense, I assume you're using VS? Important piece of info.

Comment: @PatLillis: Yes you are correct. I just mentioned intellisense as one indicaiton . but i am getting an exception stating that the field does not exist in event.

Comment: What is calling `showDetails()`? Also the documentation for the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) says that the pageX and the pageY properties might be undefined depending on the event.

Comment: It is being called on a click event of a cell in a KENDO UI Grid.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question, I thought it was actually about Intellisense. Try `e.originalEvent.pageX` a la [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8583314/2533772) and see if that works?

Comment: @PatLillis: In fact i had tried that before i asked this question. It also doe snot work same exception

Comment: Could you post a sample on JSFiddle that includes the click event?